# why setDisallowedFields for id? -- Spring petclinic example

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

From the Spring API, i understood that `@InitBinder` is used to initialize some binding rules..

In the petclinic example why we have `setdisallowed("id")`? when the id is not displayed on the form?

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
}
```

The id field is not displayed on the web page then why we are using the above code?

can we have some thing like this:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("FirstName");
}
```

as per the above code the first name field of the owner object will not be set though user enters on the form? Is that correct?

[link for the source](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petclinic/trunk/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/web/AddOwnerForm.java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it can still be submitted if the end-user modifies the page or the request (for example using FireBug). Thus he can inject values into your bound object even if you don't want this.