# @InitBinder prevents updating objects from JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jpa, data-binding

I understand @InitBinder is used for security reasons but it was causing me all kinds of issues.

I have a UserController with an update method as follows.

```
    @Secured(value={"ROLE_ADMIN"})
    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/user/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String userUpdate(User user, BindingResult userBinding, Model model, @PathVariable long id) {

    if (userBinding.hasErrors()) {
        return (String.format("user/{%s}/edit", String.valueOf(user.getId())));
    }

    try {
        userService.updateUser(user);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Unable to update user", e);
    }

    return "redirect:/user";
}
```

And I had this is my UserController as well.

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
}
```

My JSP that handles create and update is below.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <spring:bind path="user.*">
                <c:if test="${status.errors.errorCount > 0}">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <p>Error: unable to save, please check the errors below</p>
                    </div>
                </c:if>
            </spring:bind>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <h3>User - Add</h3>
            <br>

            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${user.id > 0}">
                    <c:set var="formMethod" value="PUT" />
                    <c:url var="formAction" value="/user/${user.id}" />
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <c:set var="formMethod" value="POST" />
                    <c:url var="formAction" value="/user" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>

            <sf:form method="${formMethod}" action="${formAction}" commandName="user">
                <spring:bind path="user.id">
                    <sf:hidden path="${status.expression}" id="user-id" />
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="user.firstName">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                        <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="first-name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="user.lastName">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
                        <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="last-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="user.email">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email</label>
                        <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="user.username">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="user-name">Username</label>
                        <sf:input path="${status.expression}" id="user-name" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <spring:bind path="user.password">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <sf:password path="${status.expression}" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="confirm-password">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password-confirm" id="confirm-password" class="form-control" placeholder="" />
                </div>
                <spring:bind path="user.roleId">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="role">Role</label>
                        <sf:select path="${status.expression}" id="role" class="form-control" >
                            <sf:options items="${roles}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/>
                        </sf:select>
                        <sf:errors path="${status.expression}" cssClass="error-message"></sf:errors>
                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
            </sf:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The call to userService.update(user) is calling JPA merge method. It was failing because it was trying to insert a new record that contained a unique constraint that was already in the database. Needless to say after hours of digging through code, the internet, and stack traces I realized the id coming back from the JSP was null. Once I commented out the @InitBinder method everything started working fine. This brings me to my real question, do I need @InitBinder for secuirty reasons, and if so how do I work around the issue I just described?

Comment: Admittedly I am no expert on `@InitBinder`, but I have never heard of `@InitBinder` being used for security purposes.  I was mostly under the impression it's primary use was to *bind* the web requests to some concrete objects, usually by means of PropertyEditors that are configured to convert a String into the proper Object.  If I am grossly misunderstanding it's usage, can you link to the source where you read that so I might improve my knowledge on this subject.

Comment: Ahhh maybe I misunderstood. I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801477/why-setdisallowedfields-for-id-spring-petclinic-example and thought they were blocking the ID so that a end user could not inject an ID even though its not being displayed on the form.

Comment: No, it looks like it can be used to disallow a particular field from being bound.  Wasn't aware that was an option.  But your error would now make sense because you are telling Spring to omit any incoming value 'id', so the ID for your entity would be null from the JSP.  The work around would be to look up the entity prior to saving it, or maybe associate it to the session, then pull it out when you save it so that you are operating on the session on, not expecting the JSP to pass everything back.