# Proper way of creating new record via Spring + Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to create new object and persist it in DB. In project, I have Spring-boot, Hibernate and Thymeleaf.

To provide data, I use this form:

```
<body>  
    <form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{/malt/}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
            <label>Malt name:</label>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{maltName}" />
                <label>Producer:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{producer.producerName}" />

                <label>Country:</label>
                <select class="form-control" th:field="*{country.id}">
                    <option value="0">Select country</option>
                    <option th:each="country : ${countries}"
                        th:value="${country?.id}"
                        th:text="${country?.countryName}">
                        </option>
                </select>

                <label>Malt filling:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltFilling}" />

                <label>Malt usage:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltUsage}" />

                <label>Malt EBC:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control"
                    th:field="*{maltEbc}" />


                <button class="submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Object I want to persist:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="malt")
public class Malt extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="malt_name")
    private String maltName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
    private Producer producer;

    @Column(name="malt_filling")
    private int maltFilling;

    @Column(name="malt_ebc")
    private int maltEbc;

    @Column(name="malt_usage")
    private String maltUsage;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="malts")
    private Set<Batch> batches;

    @Builder
    public Malt(Long id, String maltName, String producerName, Country country, Producer producer, int maltFilling, int maltEbc, String maltUsage) {
        super(id);
        this.maltName = maltName;
        this.producer = producer;
        this.maltFilling = maltFilling;
        this.maltEbc = maltEbc;
        this.maltUsage = maltUsage;
        this.country = country;
}
```

BaseEntity:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return this.id == null;
    }
}
```

Part of MaltController:

```
@InitBinder
public void setAllowedFields(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.setDisallowedFields("id");
}

@GetMapping("/new")
public String initCreationForm(Model model) {

    Malt malt = new Malt();
    model.addAttribute("malt", malt);

    return VIEWS_MALT_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
}

@PostMapping("/new")
public String  processCreationForm(@Valid Malt malt, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    if (StringUtils.hasLength(malt.getMaltName()) && malt.isNew()) {
        result.rejectValue("maltName", "duplicate", "already exists");
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.put("malt", malt);
        return VIEWS_MALT_CREATE_OR_UPDATE_FORM;
    } else {
        Malt savedMalt = maltService.save(malt);
        return "redirect:/malt/" + savedMalt.getId();
    }
}

@GetMapping("/{maltId}")
public ModelAndView showMalt(@PathVariable("maltId") Long maltId) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("malt/malt-show");
    mav.addObject(maltService.findById(maltId));
    return mav;
}
```

When I hit, the `Submit` button, I get the following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null" 
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
```

On the DEBUG log level, there are this logs:

```
Field [id] has been removed from PropertyValues and will not be bound, because it has not been found in the list of allowed fields

Start processing with input [id=&maltName=Dupa&producer.id=1&country.id=1&maltFilling=12&maltUsage=csd&maltEbc=34]
```

Full stacktrace:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:402)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:693)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:124)
    ... 51 more
```

I can assume, that this error occured, because `ID` was not generated. This is strange since in `BaseEntity` I have this:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
```

I was not able to find out any solution in google, that's why I am posting question here.

Link to whole project i git: https://github.com/fangirsan/maruszka-new

Comment: Why do you use WebDataBinder ?

Comment: To avoid unwanted modification of this field. This is the reason, why I can't populate `id` field? If yes, how can I change this to preserve the possibility of avoiding unwanted modification?

Comment: That's fine. I just wanted to know the reason. Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I'm at work right now, but yes, as soon I will be at home.

Comment: Full stacktrace in main thread

Comment: Just a stupid question. Are you calling GET or POST?

Comment: There are two methods - `initCreationForm (GET)`, and `processCreationForm (POST)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in this:
`<form th:object="${malt}" th:action="@{${'/malt/' + malt.id + '/edit'}}" method="post">`

`Id` wasn't set, and this caused the error. When I've changed the `th:action` it started to work.

Comment: what did you change in th:action? did you change it to this --> th:action="@{/malt/}"

Comment: I can't say, I know where the proble lay, but now I have probems with mappings and proper path

Answer (score 0):

Try to Comment out `// super(id);` in the entity's `@builder` constructor. By Doing this, your form is setting the id explicitly and it should not be done that way during POST call. It has to get generated by the persistence layer. The error says so - `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"`

Also your debug trace shows this:

`Start processing with input [id=&maltName=Dupa&producer.id=1&country.id=1&maltFilling=12&maltUsage=csd&maltEbc=34]`

It is passing null/blank string here in the ID.

Comment: Usually, I bind a form pojo and do not pass the ID from the form during Post call. can you just remove the <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" /> from your form and tryit? Also, binding an entity directly to form is not a good idea :)

Comment: Hi @Fangir, Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191849/initbinder-prevents-updating-objects-from-jsp#comment37490653_24191849 which is exactly the problem in your case.

Comment: I have commented out `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />`, and `@InitBinder` but the error still occur